# How to get P for trend in cox regression model using R?

Tags: r, cox

I got a problem with how to get P for trend in cox regression even after searching by google.

I have a DDD_1 variables which is a factor variable, containing 0,1,2.

```
res.cox = coxph(Surv(t$death_365days_duration, t$death_365days==1)~
                  DDD_1+variable 1+variable 2, data=t)
res.cox showed:
                          exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
DDD_11                        0.6342     1.5768    0.5885    0.6835
DDD_12                        0.5888     1.6985    0.5479    0.6327
                                 coef  exp(coef)   se(coef)       z Pr(>|z|)    
DDD_11                     -4.554e-01  6.342e-01  3.818e-02 -11.929  < 2e-16 ***
DDD_12                     -5.297e-01  5.888e-01  3.668e-02 -14.442  < 2e-16 ***
```

But I don't know how to get P for trend of DDD_1 variable.

Is that:

```
res.cox = coxph(Surv(t$death_365days_duration, t$death_365days==1)~
                  as.numeric(DDD_1)+variable 1+variable 2, data=t)

res.cox showed
                                 coef  exp(coef)   se(coef)       z Pr(>|z|)    
as.numeric(DDD_1)          -2.935e-01  7.457e-01  1.784e-02 -16.451  < 2e-16 ***
```

Is this P the P for trend?